# Pass checkbox ID to php file with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have some checkboxes with class='chkspec' and I would to pass the ID value of the clicked checkbox to a xxx.php file. My problems are:

1) I don't know how to pass the ID I tried 
   with "specificitem=this.id"  but I'm not sure it is the right way

2) I get this error: Undefined variable: specificitem. This occur also if I do specificitem="hello";

code is below.

if ($('.chkspec').is(":checked"))
        {

```
        xmlHttp.open('POST', "xxx.php", true);    
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
            { 
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) 
                {

                    data: {specificitem : this.id } 

                }


            }
        };
```

Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy know pure JS i'm more JQuery guy.
I would do this way :

```
if ($('.chkspec').is(":checked")) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url:"xxx.php",
        data:$('.chkspec').attr('id'),
        method:'post', 
        success:function(result){
           ;//
        }
    });
}
```

I think you get this error because data is out of nowhere.